# Identity Server 4 with ASP.NET WebApi v1

Tags: asp.net-web-api, identityserver4, owin-middleware

I've successfully integrated Identity Server 4 into asp.net MVC 4 project using OWIN/Katana middleware. But what about WebAPI v1?
I've seen a statement in the web saying that "Web API v1 is not compatible with OWIN".

Is it true? If so what is the other way to protect Api Resources?